# What's the most efficient way to move multiple wildcards in bash?

Tags: bash, wildcard, mv

What's the most efficient way to rewrite the following:

```
mv *.jpg ~/Pictures && mv *.gif ~/Pictures && mv *.png ~/Pictures
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group into one

```
mv *.{jpg,gif,png} ~/Pictures
```

If you are worrying too many files causing argument list too long

```
find -regex ".*\.\(jpg\|gif\|png\)" -print0 | xargs -r0 mv --target='~/Pictures'
```

Comment: Or more generally name several sources (which is what the above expands into); `mv *.jpg *.gif *.png ~/Pictures` -- assuming you are not very specifically using the `&&` combiner to prevent copying of GIF files if moving JPG files failed.

Answer (score 2):

Efficient? Any efficiencies in the calculations of the file names is likely to be swamped by the actual copying, but you could try:

```
mv *.jpg *.gif *.png ~/Pictures
```

If you're talking a *lot* of files, you'll have to watch out for blowing the command line size limit, but then you'd probably look into using `find` and `xargs` (I won't complicate the solution by describing that fully, especially since there's probably an answer to that expanded question elsewhere on the SO network).

Answer (score 0):

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
mv *.{jpg,gif,png} ~/Pictures
```